# Mockito - doCallRealMethod not working as expected in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

doCallRealMethod in mockito is not working as expected for me(i.e its getting mocked instead of calling real method) for method having string arguments.
I have following classes

```
Class A{
  @Autowired
  Utils utils;


  public invokerMethod(String a,String b,String c){
      utils.realMethod(a,b,c);
      .....
      ......   

 }
}
```

Class Utils:

```
Class Utils throws Exception{
        public void realMethod(String a,String b,String c)     
             if(a.equals(""))
                 throw someException();
   }
```

Class ATest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
Class ATest(){
    @Autowired
    A a;

   @MockBean
   Utils utils;

   @Test
public invokerMethodTest(){
doCallRealMethod().when(utils).realMethod(anyString(),anyString(),anyString());
      a.invokerMethod("","","");
 }
}
```

I tried replacing anyString with "", new String() but still its not working for me

Comment: Pls review your post and fix syntax errors - your code does not compile.

Comment: Pls what is your expectation to do and what is not working?

Comment: having issue here.

Comment: I solved the problem In order to doCallRealMethod work as expected, the bean should be annotated with @ SpyBean, not with @ MockBean. I changed the annotation and it worked for me.